# add validation on phone number field on customer account address page according to country magento2

Tags: magento2.4.4

I've already did validation for phone number according to country on checkout page by using layoutprocessor plugin and validation and rules js file
[image]

But I want to achieve this on customer account page as well:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Nihal, can you please share how you added validation on checkout? so i can suggest you based on that

Comment: already shared how i added validation using layoutprocessor plugin, and creating rules  expressions in rule.js

Answer (score 0):

As you already created an validation then i believe you have a rule like `validate-telephone`

Now As The `telephone` is Eav Attribute for `customer_address` entity we will use Data Patch for updating `validate_rules` for `telephone` attribute

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Setup\Patch\Data;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Customer\Api\AddressMetadataManagementInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;

class UpdateCityAttr implements DataPatchInterface
{
     /** @var ModuleDataSetupInterface */
    private $moduleDataSetup;
    /** @var EavSetupFactory */
    private $eavSetupFactory;
    /**
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function apply()
    {
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
        $eavSetup->updateAttribute(AddressMetadataManagementInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_ADDRESS, 'telephone', ['validate_rules' => {"validate-telephone":true }]);
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [];
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

You can verify this By Checking Data from this Query

```
SELECT eav_attribute.*, customer_eav_attribute.validate_rules
FROM eav_attribute
INNER JOIN customer_eav_attribute ON eav_attribute.attribute_id = customer_eav_attribute.attribute_id
where entity_type_id = 2 and attribute_code like "%telephone%";
```

Comment: first of all you can not use {"validate-telephone":true } like this it will throw syntax error.

Comment: secondly as i have multiple store and have different validation for different store it will not work as i need to change this validate-telephone according to store and cant get store in patch classes.

Comment: @nihalmalik this code is just an Example we don't add perfect syntax in answer, and Secondly you have handle that diffrent store in your validation js like if storeCode = en do this and if storeCode = ae do that

Comment: Or You can create two different child themes for both stores and override rules.js according to store requirments

Comment: what i did is get the current store and append it to the validation class like phoneUS, phoneCA etc so dont need to if else.

Comment: i think creating multiple child themes for multiple store makes it much difficult to work with.